# How can I solve the problem of a transparent top menu bar?

Tags: unity, 16.04, graphics, suspend

Occasionally, and especially after resume from suspend, the top menu bar is shown as follows. It is displayed transparently meaning that the background wallpaper is visible.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Missing top bar]

This problem comes along with another observed problem in that the closing button of windows is not properly shown.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Telegram missing closing button]

**Graphics card information:**

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel:registered: GM45 Express Chipset 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: I think reinstalling unity desktop will solve this problem

Comment: Reinstalling Unity Desktop most likely won't change a thing. This issues all have to do with how the graphical drivers wake from suspension.

Comment: @CelticWarrior how can I investigate the problem further in your suggested direction?

Comment: I suggest you edit and update your question with info of, at least, the exact graphics card/chip. Then we'll see...

Comment: @CelticWarrior please see my edited question.

Comment: Intel works with the default open source drivers. Apparently not related but just in case: Go to System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers (tab) and enable the Intel microcode (it's for the CPU but...), reboot and test. If the symptom persists you may try to update the drivers. Or someone might have a tweak to suggest.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and test Intel microcode for a while.